# How to disable item in picklist using itemDisable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, picklist

Does anyone know how to freeze any row in primefaces picklist

Or how to use itemDisabled in

Answer (score 7):

To use `itemDisabled`, simply set the attribute to an EL expression that returns a boolean value. Using PF's demo on the primefaces website, you can disable a row of a player using a condition on the player pojo like so:

```
 <p:pickList id="pojoPickList" value="#{pickListBean.players}" var="player" itemDisabled="#{player.name eq 'Messi'}"
    itemValue="#{player}" itemLabel="#{player.name}" converter="player"/>
```

The snippet above will disable the option named "Messi" in the pickList. Optionally, you can as well delegate the evaluation to a backing bean method:

```
 <p:pickList id="pojoPickList" value="#{pickListBean.players}" var="player" itemDisabled="#{backingBean.isDisabled(player)}"
    itemValue="#{player}" itemLabel="#{player.name}" converter="player"/>
```